# Camera and kmplayer issue

Tags: camera, kmplayer

There's a red vertical line appearing while playing any video using **KMPlayer** but not appearing in any other players.

Also the same exists in camera apps like windows camera and YouCam.

The red vertical line is not appearing in taken pictures...

Provide me details about this problem.

My Recent update to system is AMD CRIMSON EDITION 15.12

[image: Camera screenshot]

[image: KMPlayer screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

right click and press video(advanced) ---->Preset:quality(3GHz)

Comment: Solved in KMPlayer, but still existing in camera!